# Is there a SPICE client Java library similar to how there is one for VNC?

Tags: library, java, remote-access

There is a VNC client library called [Vernacular VNC](https://github.com/shinyhut/vernacular-vnc) written in Java for getting the graphics output and of course doing everything else a VNC client would need to do. I was wondering if there is the same thing for SPICE.

If there is a SPICE client library written in Java so I can use it in one of my Java plugins (it’s actually a Spigot plugin) so I can get the graphics output (in buffered images) and of course send input. SPICE is a newer and improved protocol, so that's why I want to use it instead of VNC.

Update: I thought I found a SPICE client JVM library, but it turns out it is for a different SPICE. I contacted the guy for help on how to use the library before I found out it wasn't what I needed. When I told him his library wasn't what I needed he pointed me to an [Android app](https://github.com/iiordanov/remote-desktop-clients/tree/master/aSPICE-app) that is a SPICE client.

It wasn't what I was picturing and I don't know much about Android apps. I don't even know if that's what I'm looking for. I was picturing a library similar to Vernacular VNC that I can access from Maven. Could I even use that android app's code?

**TL;DR**: I need a Java SPICE client library, so I can get the graphics output (specifically output to buffered images) and input keyboard/mouse data within my Java (Spigot) plugin kind of like Vernacular VNC except SPICE.